# Not being in the difference of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have two sets A and B and I say x is not an element of (A - B) does that mean x is not an element of A **and** x is an element of B, or does it mean x is not an element of A **or** x is an element of B? Which one is it and what's the reasoning behind it? I tried drawing venn diagram representations but I think I just confused myself even more. However, I'm think its x is not an element of A OR x is an element of B because we are saying x is NOT part of (A-B) and the negation of AND is OR.

Thank you.

Comment: $x \in (A \setminus B) \text {  iff  } (x \in A \text {  and  } x \notin B)$.

Comment: Thus (use De Morgan) $x \notin (A \setminus B) \text { iff  } \lnot (x \in A \text {  and  } x \notin B)$.

Comment: Conclusion : "x is not an element of A or x is an element of B".

Comment: $\{1,2,3\} \setminus \{3,4\} = \{1,2\}$.

Comment: @PeraltaLearns. It can be dangerous to say that " the negation of AND is OR". One could understand that   " not (X&Y)  " is equivalent to (A OR B), which is false.  The " negation of AND"  is rather  NAND ( not-AND) that can be symbolized with  the Sheffer stroke : X | Y ( meaning : ~ (X&Y)  ).  Using OR  with NEGATION, one can translate (X|Y) as (~X OR ~Y).  ( See DeMorgan's law) .  in the case you are dealing with, it is  " x belongs to A" that plays the role of X and  it is  " x does NOT belong to B" that plays the role of Y.

Answer (score 1):

(1) **Using logic.**

**x ∉ A-B**

is equivalent to

**it is false that :  x belongs to  the set of all objects that belong to A but do not belong to B**

which is equivalent to

**it is false that : ( x belongs to A & x does not belong to B )**

which is equivalent to ( using DeMorgan’s law)

**x does not belong to A OR x belongs to B**

which is finally equivalent to

**IF x belongs to A THEN x belongs to B.**

(2) **Using the algebra of sets.**   ( With *X’* meaning : the complement of set X and *iff* meaning  : if and only if )

x ∉ A-B

iff x∉ (A∩B’ )   ( By the definition of set difference)

iff x ∈ (A∩B’ )’  ( Since not belonging to a set S amonts to belonging to the complement of S)

iff  x ∈ (A’ U B’’ )  ( Dy DeMorgan’s law for sets)

iff x ∈ (A’ U B )    ( By complement of complement law or involution)